# Google firebase Sign-in show no email option on first sign-in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Google firebase v9. On the first sign in, usually there would be a pop up for user to choose which email to sigh in with, but for some reason, when I sign in, it automatically send me to the chat page automatically. I tried delete user in my firebase app and tried again and get the same result. What am I doing wrong?

firebase.js:

```
 import { GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
 import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
 import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

 const firebaseConfig = {//myap config};
 const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 const auth = getAuth(app);
 const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
 export { auth, provider };
```

login-page:

```
import { auth, provider } from '../firebase';
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { signInWithPopup } from 'firebase/auth';

function Header(){
const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
const navigate = useNavigate();

const signIn = (e) => {
signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
.then(() => navigate('/channel'))
.catch((error) => alert(error.message));
};

return (
   <buttononClick={!user ? signIn : () => navigate('/channel')}>Login</button/>
  );
  };
```

Maybe It's because I am already sign-in on chrome? If someone can check my code and verified, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your app is already associated with your Google account. Signing out does not sever that association.

Removing that association is described in the [Remove third-party account access](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521#remove-access), but mostly consists of going to the list of [Third-party apps with account access](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount.google.com%2Fsecurity) and removing your app from that list.

---

If that doesn't do it, have a look at the results on [forcing the account picker to show up](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+authentication+javascript+force+account+picker).

Comment: Hey, thank you for clarification. I implemented the solution on your link on 'force the account picker to show up'. I thought that was it but wanted to make sure it's not the code. Thanks a gain!